# Scala Future[Option[T]] Un Packing

Tags: scala, promise, future, for-comprehension

In the following snippet,

```
trait MyType1; trait MyType2
import scala.concurrent.Promise

val p1 = Promise[Option[MyType1]]()
val p2 = Promise[MyType2]()
```

I pass in p1 and p2 to another function where I complete the Promise using a successful Future. After the call to this function, I try to read the value in the Promise:

```
trait Test {
  // get the Future from the promise
  val f1 = p1.future
  val f2 = p2.future

  for {
    someF1Elem <- f1
    f1Elem     <- someF1Elem
    f2Elem     <- f1Elem
  } yield {
    // do something with f1Elem and f2Elem
    "..."
  }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get some compiler issues.

```
Error:(52, 19) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Nothing]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
      flElem     <- someF1Elem
                  ^
```

IntelliJ shows no errors or what-so-ever and the types look aligned. But I'm not sure why the compiler is unhappy! Any clues?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your for comprehension types must be consistent, so you cannot freely mix `Option` and `Future` in the way you do.

In your example, `f1` returns a `Future[Option[MyType1]]` while `f2` returns a `Future[MyType2]`

Remember that a for comprehension desugars to a series of `flatMap`/`map` and potentially `withFilter`.

Also the (simplified) signatures of `flatMap` for `Future[A]` and `Option[A]` are

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => Future[B]): Future[B]
def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

The first two steps of the for-comprehension desugar to

```
f1.flatMap { someF1Elem =>
  someF1Elem.flatMap { f1Elem => // this returns a `Option[MyType1]`
     ...
  }
}
```

see the error now?

---

Now, to fix this there's a few approaches you can follow. One very handy is to use Monad Transformers, which allow you to combine (for instance) `Future` and `Option` into a single monad type `OptionT`.

Specifically you can go back and forth from `Future[Option[A]]` to `OptionT[Future, A]`. The basic idea is that you can flatMap on the latter and extract a value of type `A`.

But before that, you need to make your types of the "right shape", so that both are a `Future[Option[Something]]`

Here's an example using scalaz

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._ ; import scalaz.OptionT._
import scala.concurrent.{ Promise, Future }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

trait MyType1
trait MyType2

val p1 = Promise[Option[MyType1]]()
val p2 = Promise[MyType2]()

val f1 = p1.future
val f2 = p2.future 

val res = for {
  f1Elem <- optionT(f1)
  f2Elem <- f2.liftM[OptionT]
} yield {
  println(s"$f1Elem $f2Elem")
}
```

`optionT` builds an `OptionT[Future, A]` given a `Future[Option[A]]`, while `liftM[OptionT]` achieves the same when you have a `Future[A]`

The type of `res` is `OptionT[Future, Unit]` in this case, and you can get a `Future[Option[Unit]]` by calling `run` on it.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at ["How does yield work"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html), your for comprehension is equivalent to

```
f1.flatMap(someF1Elem: Option[MyType1] => 
  someF1Elem.flatMap(f1Elem => 
    f1Elem.map(f2Elem =>
      "..."
    )
  )
)
```

Basically what happens is this: `flatMap` on a `Future` is defined to take a function that returns another `Future`.
This gives you a similar error:

`<console>:64: error: value map is not a member of MyType1
               f1Elem.map(f2Elem =>
                      ^
<console>:63: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Nothing]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
             someF1Elem.flatMap(f1Elem =>
                               ^`

If you want the operation to perform asynchronously, i.e. really mapping the `Future` instances, you will have to get back to a `Future[Option[X]]`. As Kim suggested, you can nest the comprehension:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}

def test: Future[Option[String]] = {
  val p1 = Promise[Option[MyType1]]()
  val p2 = Promise[MyType2]()
  // ... run code that completes the promises

  val f1 = p1.future
  val f2 = p2.future

  for {
    someF1Elem: Option[MyType1] <- f1
    f2Elem     <- f2
  } yield {
    for (f1Elem <- someF1Elem) yield "something"
  }
}
```

You could also make the resulting `Future` fail when the option is not defined (`NoSuchElementException`)

```
def test: Future[String] = {
  val p1 = Promise[Option[MyType1]]()
  val p2 = Promise[MyType2]()
  // ... run code that completes the promises

  val f1 = p1.future
  val f2 = p2.future

  for {
    someF1Elem: Option[MyType1] <- f1
    f2Elem <- f2
  } yield {
    val f1Elem = someF1Elem.get  // may cause an exception and fail the future
    "something"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a for comprehension, the expressions on the right hand side of the `<-` have to have compatible types. That is because for comprehensions are basically syntactic sugar for nested `flatMap` calls. To solve this problem, you can either have a for comprehension nested within another for comprehension or you can use methods like `get` or `map` on the `Option`s.

Another option is to use [monad transformers](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html), but that's beyond the scope of this answer.